# how to flush the content of all the files with .dat extension in a directory?

Tags: files, io-redirection

In a directory I have some files with .dat extension, I want to empty all such files without deleting those files from the directory.

I tried to achieve it like this but it didn't worked

```
> *.dat
-bash: *.dat: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
:|tee -- *.dat
```

Or the `zsh` (with `multios`) equivalent:

```
:>*.dat
```

Though because that opens all the files concurrently, you may reach the limit on the maximum number of open file descriptors if there's a large number of files.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
for x in *.dat
do
    > "$x"
done
```

this basically loop trough all files, performing a `>` on them.

Answer (score 3):

If your system has the `truncate` utility (from GNU coreutils) you could do

```
truncate -s 0 -c -- *.dat
```

The `-s 0` sets the size to zero, while `-c` prevents creation of a new file with literal name `*.dat` in the case that there are no matches, if your shell returns the unexpanded `*.dat` in that case.

Comment: Though there is now a `truncate` command in GNU coreutils (since 7.0, 2008), the command originates (I beleive) in FreeBSD (4.2, 2000). And you need `-s` (the short option also supported by GNU truncate) instead of `--size` there. Both FreeBSD and GNU `truncate` support a `-c` option to avoid creating the file if it doesn't exist. Otherwise, using `failglob` (to get a behaviour similar to zsh/fish/csh/tcsh/thomson-sh) would make more sense than `noglob`

Comment: Ah. I see you mention the `--no-create` already (you need `-c` in FreeBSD)

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas I have re-written to try to incorporate your comments - avoiding `nullglob` / `failglob` altogether since I don't understand them well enough ;)